# Does the release of Google Wallet change any of the capabilities available to Android developers?

Tags: android, nfc

Recently, Google released Google Wallet and additionally released an update for Sprint Nexus S phones ([CNET](http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-19736_7-20108462-251/samsung-nexus-s-4g-update-to-bring-google-wallet-support/) , [NFCWorld](http://www.nfcworld.com/2011/07/11/38469/sprint-to-begin-enabling-google-wallet-today/) ) to enable the secure elements on the phone, (probably the SmartMax chip).

-Can we presume that, despite Google's great protestations at Google I/O (at 55 minutes of [Google I/O Presentation](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=49L7z3rxz4Q) ), the Android phones are in fact implementing Google Wallet using the NFC chip in *card emulation mode*?

-Have there been attempts by third parties to gain access to the secure elements on the phones using the same means as Wallet using the new update? I'm familiar with [SEEK](http://code.google.com/p/seek-for-android/) , but currently that's impractical because it requires flashing the phone to access internal secure elements.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- according to my understanding the Google (or Samsung) or other TSM will be the only entities who will be ever allowed to make upload of the cardlets to the secure element, so even API will be open to the scale you can call the cardlet (I think there is JavaCard on SmartMX) you will not be upload anything there.
- Yes, Google Wallet is working in the card emulation mode - this is the only mode they can in a secure way be compatible with MasterCard PayPass
- Google will probably never allow small companies to access the secure element. They can have deal with big players, banks, Visa/MasterCard/Amex, mobile network operators, some TSM...
- Anyway we are living in the changing world, so possibilities are open - they can somehow change their mind, but I will not rely on the option that the built-in secure element will be ever opened.

BR
STeN

Comment: Do you have a source for the card emulation part? Android implements its own peer-to-peer NDEF push protocol in the standard SDK - it could be possible that Google and MasterCard came up with a proprietary p2p protocol (assuming MasterCard can roll out new software to their PayPass terminals)?

Comment: Hi, I do not have any source code. But for the card emulation mode, there is not the p2p mode used. The standard here is EMV(www.emvco.com) - in order to be compatible with existing accepting machines (ATM, POS,...) the phone must run in the card emulation mode, in which it emulates the same (plastic) payment card, which you normally use (e.g. dual interface card). The steps for an EMV transaction are pretty complicated, it includes various authentication, verifications, etc.

Comment: Yeah, I had a look inside the Google Wallet APK; I saw some references to EMV. Interesting that they've implemented card emulation on their own without publishing any APIs (so far).

Comment: Hi,handling the card emulation mode is more difficult... Even the API for card emulation will be available - it will be useless for you, since you will have no possibility to install cardlet on the secure element - the java card area in built-in SmartMX chip is protected by secure keys, which are controlled by Google. If not on Smart MX, the cardlet can be installed on the UICC (SIM card). It is connected via SWP with the NFC controller, which gives the SIM the contactless interface - this you cannot use directly from the phone.